# How can I fix my for loops for a card game?

Tags: python, for-loop

This issue seems pretty simple but I'm stuck on it... I want to create multiple rounds of a for loop-based card game until the computer or user wins. My for loop is not working and stops immediately after naming how many cards are left.

I have tried messing around with the indentation and the style of the for loop.

```
def card_game():

    print("New Game start")

    cards = int(21)

    comp_pick = 0


    user_choice = input("Do you want to go first? y/n: ")


    if user_choice == "y":

        for n in range(cards):

            while n < 21 and n > 0:

                return print("There are",cards - comp_pick,"cards left")

            user_pick = int(input("How many cards do you pick? (1-3): "))
            comp_pick = int(4 - user_pick)

            if user_pick > int(3):
                return print("You cannot pick",user_pick,"cards")

            elif user_pick < int(1):
                return print("You cannot pick",user_pick,"cards")

            else:
                cards = cards - user_pick
                if comp_pick == 1:
                    return print("There are",cards,"left \n\tI pick",comp_pick,"card")
                else:
                    return print("There are",cards,"left \n\tI pick",comp_pick,"cards")

            n = cards - comp_pick


    if user_choice == "n":
        #assuming the computer will always pick 1 card first
        #taking 1 card will allow the number of cards to remain divisible by 4

        return print("There are",cards,"cards left \n\tI pick 1 card \nThere are 20 cards left")

        for n in range(1, 20):

            while n < 20 and n > 0:

                user_pick = int(input("How many cards do you pick? (1-3): "))

            if user_pick > int(3):
                return print("You cannot pick",user_pick,"cards")

            if user_pick < int(1):
                return print("You cannot pick",user_pick,"cards")

            else:
                cards = cards - user_pick
                comp_pick = 4 - user_pick
                if comp_pick == 1:
                    return print("There are",cards,"left \n\tI pick",comp_pick,"card")
                else:
                    return print("There are",cards,"left \n\tI pick",comp_pick,"cards")

            n = cards - comp_pick
```

I expect the output to be:

```
There are 21 cards left

How many cards do you pick (1-3): 3
    You picked 3 cards


There are 18 cards left

    I pick 2 cards

-----------------------------------------

There are 16 cards left

How many cards do you pick (1-3): 4
```

This is based off if the user decides to go first. I got the first couple of lines, but my `for` loop does not continue for the next game.

Comment: You have too many `return` statements. If you just need to print, you only need `print`, not `return print`. That's what is making the code exit as soon as it printed a string.

Comment: Thank you! I took those out and took out the while loop which was not necessary

Comment: I've added an answer with more code that might be helpful, if you want to check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue was definitely the `return print` statements, and as you realized, there is no real need for the `while` loops. Since the two blocks after the `y/n` question are pretty much identical, you could make a function so that it consolidates the code, and makes it more readable. There were other little things here and there that I adjusted, but there's still missing the winning logic. Anyhow, hope this helps now and in the future.

```
    def card_loop(start_count):
        cards = start_count  # how many cards we start with, as it depends

        while cards > 0:  # it is always decremented, so just check for zero threshold
            print("There are", cards, "cards left")
            user_pick = int(input("How many cards do you pick? (1-3): "))
            if 1 <= user_pick <= 3:
                # valid user pick, proceed with calculations
                cards -= user_pick  # cards left from user pick
                comp_pick = 4 - user_pick  # computer pick logic
                print("There are", cards, "left \n\tI pick", comp_pick, "card")
                cards -= comp_pick  # cards left from computer pick

            else:
                # invalid user pick, do nothing, will ask user to pick again
                print("You cannot pick", user_pick, "cards")


    def card_game():
        print("New Game start")
        user_choice = input("Do you want to go first? y/n: ")

        if user_choice == "y":
            card_loop(21)

        elif user_choice == "n":
            # assuming the computer will always pick 1 card first
            # taking 1 card will allow the number of cards to remain divisible by 4
            card_loop(20)


    card_game()
```

Comment: This helped immensely. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your loop logic is convoluted.  Also, you've tried to code several game features at once, without testing any of them, which makes your current debugging harder.  Let's tackle just the game loop.  Decompose the hierarchy, perhaps something like this:

```
# Play one game.
# Start with 20 cards
# Continue until there are no cards left

deck = 20
while deck > 0:
    # Each player gets a turn: human first
    human_take = int(input("How many cards do you want?"))
    deck -= human_take
    print("You took", human_take, "cards; there are", deck, "remaining")

    computer_take = 4 - human_take
    deck -= computer_take
    print("You took", computer_take, "cards; there are", deck, "remaining")
```

That's the gist of the game loop you might want.  I've omitted the input validation (there are plenty of answers on this site for that topic), among other things.

Can you continue from there?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I am now working on the last bit of code to making sure once the remaining card value reaches 1 or 0, that the correct output will display in my Shell and the game will be over.

Answer (score 0):

Like Sal said, the `return` statement will exit the function. Also the line `n = cards - comp_pick` gets overridden in the for statement. See this example:

```py
for n in range(10):
    print(n)
    n += 2
```

One would think that this prints: `0, 2, 4, ...18`, but it actually prints: `0, 1, 2 ... 9`. This is because the `range` function returns a lazily computed list. Therefore the above code block can be written as:

```py
for n in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]:
    print(n)
    n += 2
```

Here it is clear that after the line `n += 2`, `n` is then assigned to the next element in the list.